# What is the difference between the following two blocks of code?

Tags: node.js, functional-programming, request, currying

I've been working on `Node.js` and encountered some problem with the following code, the problem is solved, but I want to know why:
(`_` is `lodash`, `request` is the `request` `^2.60.0` package in npm)

```
 var send = (options, type) =>
     (req, res, next) => {
         var defaultOptions = {
             baseUrl: config.urlprefix,
             method: 'GET',
             encoding: 'utf8',
             header: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             }
         }
         options = options || {};

         if (_.isFunction(options)) {
             options = _.assign(defaultOptions, options(req));
         }
         else if (_.isObject(options)) {
             options = _.assign(defaultOptions, options);
         }

         request(options, parseResToJSONAndSend(res, type));
     };
```

and this does not work well: The second(and more) time I call `send`, the `options` parameter in
`request` is just the same as the first time I call `send`, even if I changed the params pass to `send`, and it will never change after that.

So I change the code to the following:

```
 var send = (options, type) =>
     (req, res, next) => {
         var defaultOptions = {
             baseUrl: config.urlprefix,
             method: 'GET',
             encoding: 'utf8',
             header: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             }
         }
         var opt = options || {};

         if (_.isFunction(options)) {
             opt = _.assign(defaultOptions, opt(req));
         }
         else if (_.isObject(options)) {
             opt = _.assign(defaultOptions, opt);
         }

         request(opt, parseResToJSONAndSend(res, type));
     };
```

and this time it works well. But I don't know where the problem is.
Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

---

to make it clear:
the def of `stock` controller:

```
var apis = {
    stocks: (req) => ({
        url: SOME_URL
    }),
    ...
};

var mod = {};
Object.keys(apis).map((key) => {
    mod[key] = request(apis[key]);
});
module.exports = mod;
```

the use of `stock` controller:

```
router.get('/some-path',stock.stocks);
```

def of `parseResToJSONAndSend`:

```
var parseResToJSONAndSend = (res, type) =>
    (err, resp, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Response err", err);
        } else if (resp.statusCode < 200 || resp.statusCode > 299) {
            console.log("Status code not in range 200..299:", resp.statusCode, resp.request.uri.href);
        } else {
            console.log(resp.request.uri.href, resp.statusCode);
            try {
                if (type == 'json') {
                    res.json(JSON.parse(data));
                }
                else {
                    res.send(data);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("Err in JSON parse", e);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: yes, the second time I pass a different options

Comment: This is where I dislike some of the ES6 shortcut syntax.  If you wrote this out in ES5 syntax, I bet it would be more obvious to you what is happening.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that there is no obvious reason why this happens?

Comment: No.  I mean the => syntax and implicit returns can obscure what is actually happening.  I'd like to see a couple of examples of the calling code (each passing different `options` arguments) to know better what is going on.

Comment: OK. I'll edit the question.

Comment: You added some code, but it doesn't look like you added any code examples that call `send()` and pass it an options object and those are the operative examples I was looking for.

Comment: about 5 banks accounts, 3 ounces, and 2 vehicles.

Comment: Yeah. When navigating to config.urlprefix/some-path, express.js use router.get, and calls stock.stocks. So the 'req' obj is passed by express.js. Sorry for late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first block, `_.assign(defaultOptions, options(req))` changed the value of options, so the param `options` passed to `send` is changed to an object, which make the followed calls to `send` go into the `else if` branch.

In the second block, `_.assign(defaultOptions, options(req))` will also change the param passed to `send`. So it is not right, either.

Finally the code was changed to:

```
var send = (options, type) =>
    (req, res, next) => {
        var defaultOptions = {
            baseUrl: config.urlprefix,
            method: 'GET',
            encoding: 'utf8',
            header: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        var opt = _.cloneDeep(options || {});

        if (_.isFunction(options)) {
            opt = _.assign({}, defaultOptions, options(req));
        }
        else if (_.isObject(options)) {
            opt = _.assign({}, defaultOptions, opt);
        }

        request(opt, parseResToJSONAndSend(res, type));
    };
```